# Excel Addin Event API - DoubleClick

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Does anyone know why he office.js API does not expose a Cell DoubleClick event?  This is an event that is available on traditional COM addins, and it seems like an intentional omission.  The cell double-click event is useful for interactive reporting where a user can double-click on a cell value to "drill" into underlying data.

Does anyone have any work-arounds or suggestions on how to possibly handle this?

Comment: They do have click events, just not double click.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not all features available for COM add-ins are exposed by Office JavaScript API (`OfficeJS`).

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on Tech Community where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process, so post your feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Yup, I did this already.  Last activity on that idea is from 2022.  It seems like such an obvious omission, they must have consciously avoided this event hook for some reason.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/add-api-for-excel-double-click-event/idi-p/2466341

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that because the event handler runs asynchronously and returns a promise, the ability to "cancel" the cell edit mode may not be practical vs the COM Addin where the event handler runs synchronously and within the same Excel process.  But I cannot imagine that this event was left out on accident or that the developers didn't anticipate this event being widely leveraged.